# com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCachedFile() method doesn't exist in Java 7 Update 6

Tags: java

I need the path file return by **com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCachedFile(location)** for a launcher.This method was working fine in Java 5 and Java 6, but when I updated to Java 7, it is not available anymore. Does anybody know how can i get the file path return by that method in cmd or any other method to obtain the path file?

Comment: [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

Comment: Unfortunately thats why you should avoid com.sun.* stuff it at all possible

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's in the package `com.sun` indicates that it's Sun-implementation-specific and shouldn't be relied upon. I think you need a much more portable way of doing what you want.

Comment: I searched a command in cmd to find out the path from CacheEntry that i need to use to create the luncher, but i did't find anything.What other packages do you recommand me to use?

Comment: I don't know, I'm afraid. I'm not familiar with this area

Answer (score 0):

```
com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.getCacheEntry(new URL(fileName), null).getDataFile();
```